# iOS App - LaunchScreen.storyboard for wCompact hRegular double the size of everything

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to help out a colleague with the launch screen storyboard for iOS devices and we're running into a really odd issue.

Whenever we set the size class through Xcode the background image is always fullscreen and the logo always sits in the middle of the screen no matter what, but when we publish the app and test it on an iPhone 4s or 5c (don't have a 5 to hand) the logo is double the size specified in the width and height of the imageView tag in the XML.

The background image and logo are centered correctly on an iPhone 6, 6 plus and iPad 4th Gen.

Does anyone know if I need to offset the position of the logo by 1/2 to compensate for retina?

Comment: Is the `ContentMode` of the ImageView set to `ScaleAspectFit`?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Yep, ContentMode is set the ScaleAspectFit. I've actually found the solution now so I'll add my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way around this issue for me was the set the size class to wAny hAny and set constraints to be horizontal and vertical center aligned as well as constraining the aspect ratio and setting the logo to a fixed size.